# no suitable method found for Collections.sort(List )

Tags: java, collections

Currently I am learning Java.

I am having problem with `java.utils.Collections`, NetBeans keep on giving me this error.

```
 no suitable method found for sort(List<MovieSession>)
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: MovieSession
        upper bounds: Comparable<? super T#1>)
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>
```

I have following class MovieSession

```
public class MovieSession implements Comparable<MovieSession> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MovieSession currentMovieSession) { 

    }
}
```

And main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   List<MovieSession> movieSessions = new ArrayList<MovieSession>();

   MovieSession cinema1 = new MovieSession("XYZ", 'R', new Time(10, 10, 10));
   MovieSession cinema2 = new MovieSession("ABC", 'G', new Time(11, 00, 00));

   movieSessions.add(cinema1);
   movieSessions.add(cinema2);
   Collections.sort(movieSessions);
   System.out.print(movieSessions);    
}
```

Not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: Why are you using raw types everywhere?

Comment: Oh, wait, they just look raw because you didn't code-format correctly.

Comment: thanks for the edit  it always happens with me

Comment: @WonderGal so the statements at the bottom are not inside a method?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw  they are inside the main method

Comment: I don't think we're going to be able to help without a completely reproducible piece of code because it sure looks fine to me from here, but this is not the whole code afterall

Comment: You don't need `else if (getSessionTime().compareTo(currentMovieSession.getSessionTime()) == 0)` where just `else` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code, added the missing bits, and it runs without any errors

Main:

```
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class TestBed {

public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<MovieSession> movieSessions = new ArrayList<MovieSession>();

        MovieSession session1 = new MovieSession("Logan", 'R', new Time(10, 10, 10));
        MovieSession session2 = new MovieSession("Baby Boss", 'G', new Time(11, 00, 00));
        MovieSession session3 = new MovieSession("Guardians Of The Galaxy ", 'M', new Time(9, 30, 00));
        MovieSession session4 = new MovieSession("Moana", 'G', new Time(13, 45, 00));


        movieSessions.add(session1);
        movieSessions.add(session2);
        movieSessions.add(session3);
        movieSessions.add(session4);

        Collections.sort(movieSessions);
        System.out.println(movieSessions);
    }

}
```

MovieSession:

```
import java.sql.Time;

public class MovieSession implements Comparable<MovieSession> {

    private Time sessionTime;
    private String movieName;
    private char rating;

    public MovieSession(String mn, char rtg, Time tm){
        this.sessionTime = tm;
        this.movieName = mn;
        this.rating = rtg;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MovieSession currentMovieSession) {
        if (getSessionTime().compareTo(currentMovieSession.getSessionTime()) > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (getSessionTime().compareTo(currentMovieSession.getSessionTime()) < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else if (getSessionTime().compareTo(currentMovieSession.getSessionTime()) == 0) {
            if (getMovieName().compareTo(currentMovieSession.getMovieName()) > 0) {
                return 1;
            } else if (getMovieName().compareTo(currentMovieSession.getMovieName()) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s - %s - %s", movieName, rating, sessionTime);
    }


    public Time getSessionTime() {
        return sessionTime;
    }


    public void setSessionTime(Time sessionTime) {
        this.sessionTime = sessionTime;
    }


    public String getMovieName() {
        return movieName;
    }


    public void setMovieName(String movieName) {
        this.movieName = movieName;
    }

}
```

Output:
[Guardians Of The Galaxy  - M - 09:30:00, Logan - R - 10:10:10, Baby Boss - G - 11:00:00, Moana - G - 13:45:00]

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help @DevonSutherland . But I still have the same error. Is it because my main method is inside MovieSession?

Comment: So I went ahead and tried that but I still can't reproduce your error, sorry. Can you post your imports and the actual exception?

Comment: Why not `return getMovieName().compareTo(currentMovieSession.getMovieName());` for the secondary comparison?

Comment: @DevonSutherland I have updated my question with the error. Thanks